# Function or loop to change names from data in R, to iterate many times

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization

I am currently working with a big amount of data. The data is splitted by years (from 1999 to 2018), where I have to perform several calculations (mean, sd...) for each year, and I would like to make a function or a loop that would iterate to it, changing the names
This is a sample:

```
zoocstack98 <- stack(zoocfiles98, varname = "zooc") #stack of layers from each 
zoocstack99 <- stack(zoocfiles99, varname = "zooc")
zoocstack00 <- stack(zoocfiles00, varname = "zooc")
#Reduce extent to the Azores region

zoocstack_new98<-crop(zoocstack98, extent(-36,-20,33,44))#longitude y luego latitude
zoocstack_new99<-crop(zoocstack99, extent(-36,-20,33,44))
zoocstack_new00<-crop(zoocstack00, extent(-36,-20,33,44))



#### 1998

index98 <- seq(as.Date('1998-01-01'), as.Date('1998-12-31'), by='day')  
corresponding to dates of environmental layers
month98<-month(index98)
zoocstack_new98new <- raster::setZ(zoocstack_new98,month98) #assign each raster layer in stack 
a timestamp by date
mean_zooc_month98 <- zApply(zoocstack_new98new, by=month98, mean, na.rm=T) #average over each 
layer in stack by day of year
sd_zooc_month98 <- zApply(zoocstack_new98new, by=month98, sd, na.rm=T) #average over each 
layer in stack by day of year


####1999
index99 <- seq(as.Date('1999-01-01'), as.Date('1999-12-31'), by='day') 
month<-month(index99)
zoocstack_new99new <- raster::setZ(zoocstack_new99,month) 
mean_zooc_month99 <- zApply(zoocstack_new99new, by=month, mean, na.rm=T) 
sd_zooc_month99 <- zApply(zoocstack_new99new, by=month, sd, na.rm=T) 

####2000
index00 <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2000-12-31'), by='day') 
month<-month(index00)
zoocstack_new00new <- raster::setZ(zoocstack_new00,month) 
mean_zooc_month00 <- zApply(zoocstack_new00new, by=month, mean, na.rm=T) 
sd_zooc_month00 <- zApply(zoocstack_new00new, by=month, sd, na.rm=T)
```

I would like to find a way of doing this automaticly, instead of copying and replacing the names, which is causing me to make a lot of mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using a `list` of data.frames instead of multiple single data frames. Naming an object in a `list` is quite simple.

Comment: can you go a little further in detail? Im a begginer user

Comment: Perhaps I missunderstood your question: How are the data provided? Do you already have multiple data.frames or do you have many files named (for example) `zoocstack_new98` or `zoocstack_new99`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I saw I had the title a bit confusing. After some opearations I get also dataframes where I perform repetitive operations, so in general Im just looking for a way to do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

if you do not know how to write a loop, you probably should read (again) some intro to R text about loops, and functions, and lapply.

I would write a function that process one year. I am assuming that you get the files for one year with `list.files`, based on the year being in the filename; but you probably need to adjust that line to make it work for you. If that does not work, you could instead pass two arguments to the function (the filenames and the year)

```
f <- function(year) {
    zfiles <- list.files(".", pattern=year)
    zoo <- stack(zfiles, varname = "zooc")
    zoo <- crop(zoo, extent(-36,-20,33,44))
    index <- seq(as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01')), as.Date(past0(year, '-12-31')), by='day')  
    month <- month(index)
    zoo <- raster::setZ(zoo, month) 
    zApply(zoo, by=month, mean, na.rm=T)
}
```

Now call the function for one year:

```
mean98 <- f(1998)
```

Or for a range of years

```
x <- lapply(1998:2000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am currently lookinf in manuals how to do the operations I intend to, but it is always easier and quicker if someone explains it to you.

Comment: I understand most of the lines but the "list.files" I cant make it work properly